Application behaves weirdly with `>>`, replaces lines instead of appending
The application itself is not in question, I am just wondering how the Bash around is not behaving as I expected it to, like somehow whatever behaviour this application has, it is leaking out in a way I can't explain why.
For context, the application is patsh, it is meant for Nix (as in the package manager) stuff, but essentially it takes some input file, and rewrites it based on some rules and then saves it to the output file (which here is /dev/stdout), in this context, it doesn't rewrite anything, so it is essentially cp. Here is the setup:
$ cat <<EOF > foo
1
2
3
4
5
6
EOF

$ cat <<EOF > bar
a
b
c
EOF

$ { patsh -f bar /dev/stdout; } >> foo  # Using braces to avoid any ambiguity...

$ cat foo  # It replaced instead of appending
a
b
c
4
5
6

$ cat <(patsh -f bar /dev/stdout) >> foo  # Does what I expected

$ cat foo
a
b
c
4
5
6
a
b
c

Can anyone explain this behaviour?


{ patsh -f bar /dev/stdout; } >> foo


In Linux or Cygwin opening /dev/stdout does not duplicate the descriptor, it opens the same file anew, so a separate open file description gets created.
Apparently patsh opens the file specified by the operand not in append mode. Then the tool does not write to its stdout (file descriptor 1), it writes to the new descriptor pointing to the new open file description that happens to point to the same file as the actual stdout (because you specified /dev/stdout), but the mode is independent and in this case it's actually different.
If by opening /dev/stdout the program got a file descriptor that was a duplicate of stdout (fd 1), i.e. a file descriptor pointing to the same open file description as stdout (equivalent of doing dup(1)), then the command would work as you expected. In some Unices /dev/stdout, /dev/stdin, /dev/stderr, /dev/fd/n work exactly like this; but not in Linux.


cat <(patsh -f bar /dev/stdout) >> foo


Inside <(…) the stdout is a pipe. Like above, patsh opens the same file as its stdout anew, but now it doesn't matter because the file is a pipe and writing to a pipe always adds data to the end of the stream. The pipe is being read by cat. Only cat prints to foo. It does this using its actual stdout (as opposed to opening the same file anew via /dev/stdout) whose append mode has been set by >> you used; so this works as you expected.

Why is -f ever needed when the file is /dev/stdout?

Sorry!  @Mathias Sven, why is -f /dev/stdout ever needed?

The application requires the -f flag when the output file already exists, and since /dev/stdout is an existing file, it requires that flag. It uses the flag here, passing it to the create_new method.

What does "open the same file anew" mean when stdout is a pipe?

Seems like you could also do patsh -f bar /dev/stdout | cat >> foo

@Barmar "Open the same file anew" means "create a new open file description". It does not matter if the file is a pipe or whatever.

@KamilMaciorowski dup2() creates a new open file descriptor, but you seem to be saying that it doesn't act the same.

@Bamar Please read this answer to the question I linked to in my answer. "File descriptor" and "open file description" are different things.
